# delete в inner jon не удаляет

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы не могу сделать так что бы поле с одним и тем же именем удалялось

```html
DELETE images_big.filename_small, filename_small FROM images_big INNER JOIN images_ava ON images_big.filename_small = images_ava.filename_small WHERE images_ava.filename_small = small_5836c72b26beb;
```

такая вот ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
поверял поле и  имя в этом поле соответствуют точно есть в таблице

Comment: delete удаляет записи целиком. нельзя удалить одно поле. поэтому в синтаксисе delete не предусмотрено указание конкретных по\лей которые надо удалять. пишется обычно `delete таблица.* from ...`

Comment: DELETE * FROM images_big INNER JOIN images_ava ON images_big.filename_small = images_ava.filename_small WHERE images_ava.filename_small = small_5836c72b26beb